# Manipulate umbraco content using a console application

Tags: c#, console-application, umbraco

This is a noob question but I'm searching for some time and can't find any useful information.

I need to develop a rotine (console application) that will read and write content into a umbraco site. I've already read that you can do that with web forms and mvc application.

But I need to use umbraco like an external source. I need to do something like we do with Word documents. For example: open the file, read the file, write some things and save it.

I've already installed the API using
PM> Install-Package UmbracoCms -Pre

Some things I've already read:
http://nishantwork.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/umbraco-create-custom-content-node-in-umbraco-by-c/
https://github.com/sitereactor/umbraco-console-example

What is the best to achieve that? I don't know how to do it exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to help anyone with the same issue. I'm find out a web service in umbraco and i'm currently using that (until now for reading information only, but as far as I know we can write infomation also). Altought there's little documentation is easy to use.
But to use that you need to set  `<webservices enabled="False">` in umbracoSettings.config . This fie is in the folder Config inside umbraco.
We have to set user rights into the webservices node also to allow the user to use the web service

```
DocumentServiceReference.documentServiceSoapClient client = new DocumentServiceReference.documentServiceSoapClient();
client.WebservicesEnabled();
DocumentServiceReference.ArrayOfDocumentCarrier documents = client.readList(parentId, username, password);

foreach (DocumentServiceReference.documentCarrier doc in documents)
{
    DocumentServiceReference.ArrayOfDocumentProperty properties = doc.DocumentProperties;
    foreach (DocumentServiceReference.documentProperty property in properties)
    {
        string key = property.Key;
        string value = property.PropertyValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an Umbraco node (document), write to it and save it from a console application.  Umbraco is basically a bunch of .Net libraries:

```
//Get the type you would like to use by its alias and the user who should be the creator of the document 
DocumentType dt = DocumentType.GetByAlias("Textpage"); 
User author = User.GetUser(0); 

//create a document with a name, a type, an umbraco user, and the ID of the document's parent page. To create a document at the root of umbraco, use the id -1 

Document doc = Document.MakeNew("My new document", dt, author, 1018); 

// Get the properties you wish to modify by it's alias and set their value
doc.getProperty("bodyText").Value = "<p>Your body text</p>";
doc.getProperty("articleDate").Value = DateTime.Now;

//after creating the document, prepare it for publishing 

doc.Publish(author);

//Tell umbraco to publish the document
umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(doc.Id);
```

See:

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/creating-a-document
http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/modifying-document-properties

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've decided use umbraco web services.

Comment: No problem.  But please proceed with caution and check out this security briefing http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2013/4/29/security-vulnerability-found-immediate-action-recommended.aspx as Umbraco recently recommended removal of the web services dll.

Comment: @amelvin You sure this code works inside a console app? I am facing this problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358594/umbraco-try-to-read-document-properties-programatically-but-always-getting-nul?noredirect=1#comment30393355_20358594