# Umbraco - Try to read document properties programatically but always getting null

Tags: umbraco

I am writing a console application to read content from my umbraco database. I am unable to get following simple code to work

```
        var doc = new Document(1081);
        Console.WriteLine("Package Id: {0}", doc.getProperty("packageId").Value);
```

There is a document in Umbraco and I have created content against that document. The content node is published and has id of 1081. The first line works fine and returns me the correct content node but second line fails to retrieve the property named `packageId`. There is a property with this name on the document type and I can see this value in the xml of the content node in `cmsContentXml` table in Umbraco database.

Is running this inside a console application a problem? I do not seem me to think so otherwise the first line of code would not have worked either.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the property of the published node in the XML cache, rather than directly from the db? Not sure if that would make any difference, but could be worth a try - if it works you could then assume the Document reference was the sticking point.

Comment: Are you referring to using `NodeFactory`? I tried that but that keeps throwing errors. I am not sure if I can use that without access to `UmbracoContext` which is available only if you are in web context. I am running inside a console app.